# JTextArea not displaying in JScrollPane?

Tags: java

For some reason the JTextArea is not being visible/displayed in the scrollPane? I'm trying to recreate a simple chat bubble and initially started off by making JPanels to serve as the bubble and overlay it with a JTextLabel but it didn't go so well because there was spacing issues/scrollpane sizing issues that got me stuck. I took a step back and just want to make the textarea work.

```
  import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class EventListeners implements ActionListener {
    private final JButton button;
    private final JTextField textField;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
//    private final JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    public EventListeners(JButton gift_button, JTextField textField, JTextArea textArea) {
        this.button = gift_button;
        this.textField = textField;
        this.textArea = textArea;
   //     this.layeredPane = ChatSystem.layeredPane;

        // Set font and text color for the JTextArea
        Font boldFont = new Font(textArea.getFont().getName(), Font.BOLD, textArea.getFont().getSize());
        textArea.setFont(boldFont);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
     //   layeredPane.add(textArea, Integer.valueOf(2));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            // Gift Button
            System.out.println("Button clicked");
        } else if (e.getSource() == textField) {
            if (!textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                String message = textField.getText();
                textField.setText("");

                // Debugging: Print the message to console
                System.out.println("Message: " + message);

                // Append the message to the JTextArea on the EDT
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        textArea.setLineWrap(true);  
                        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

                        textArea.append("You: " + message + "\n");
                        System.out.println("Test:" + message);
                        
                    }
                });

                // Debugging: Print the text area content to console
                System.out.println("Text Area Content:\n" + textArea.getText());

                // Scroll to the bottom of the JTextArea on the EDT
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```lua
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ChatUI {
    static JTextField chat_input = new JTextField(8);
    static JPanel inner_background = new JPanel();
    static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 2);
    static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    public static String getTextFieldText() {
        return chat_input.getText();
    }

    public static void createScrollingList(JLayeredPane layeredPane) {
        // Other settings for the inner background panel
        // inner_background.setBackground(Color.decode("#111214"));
        inner_background.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#111214"), 2, true));
        inner_background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inner_background, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        inner_background.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 1000)); // Adjust the preferred size as needed
    
        // Create a new JScrollPane and add the inner_background panel to it
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(20, 200, 330, 450);
    
        // Auto-scrolls down
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
       // inner_background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Set the background color of the scroll pane and its viewport
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.decode("#111214"));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.decode("#111214"));
    
        // Add the scroll pane to the layered pane
        layeredPane.add(scrollPane, Integer.valueOf(2));
    
        // Ensure the layout is updated
        inner_background.revalidate();
        inner_background.repaint();
    }
    

    static void UIVisuals(JFrame frame, JLayeredPane layeredPane) {
        // Left frame
        JPanel topBackground = new JPanel();
        topBackground.setBackground(Color.decode("#62D0F6"));
        topBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 80);

        // Right frame
        JPanel rightFrame = new JPanel();
        rightFrame.setBackground(Color.decode("#9B90B2"));
        rightFrame.setBounds(20, 40, 20, 20);

        // Add frames to layeredPane
        layeredPane.add(rightFrame, Integer.valueOf(1));
        layeredPane.add(topBackground, Integer.valueOf(1));

        // User_Icon
        ImageIcon userIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/pokec/OneDrive/Pictures/user_java_icon.png");
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel(userIcon);
        userLabel.setBounds(0, 30, userIcon.getIconWidth(), userIcon.getIconHeight()); // Adjust the bounds as needed
        layeredPane.add(userLabel, Integer.valueOf(2));

        // Emoji Button
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\pokec\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\gift_icon.png");

        // Create a JButton and set the image icon
        JButton gift_button = new JButton(imageIcon);
        gift_button.setBounds(320, 670, 40, 40);
        layeredPane.add(gift_button, Integer.valueOf(2));

        // Make button transparent
        gift_button.setOpaque(false);
        gift_button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        gift_button.setBorderPainted(false);

        // Texting Panel
        chat_input.setBackground(Color.decode("#383A40"));
        chat_input.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        chat_input.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#4B4D54"), 1, true));

        // Font setup
        Font f3 = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 15);
        chat_input.setFont(f3);

        // Adjust the position and size of the chat input
        chat_input.setBounds(20, 670, 280, 40);
        layeredPane.add(chat_input, Integer.valueOf(1));

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(null); // Set null layout for precise positioning
        bottomPanel.add(chat_input);

        // Add components to layeredPane
        layeredPane.add(chat_input, Integer.valueOf(1));
        layeredPane.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Event Listeners
        EventListeners eventListeners = new EventListeners(gift_button, chat_input, textArea);
        chat_input.addActionListener(eventListeners);
        gift_button.addActionListener(eventListeners);


        createScrollingList(layeredPane);
    }
}
```

I feel the issue is with my setup of the scrollPane and inner_background in ChatUI.java but unsure. I know its not a textcolor issue but rather a possible layout problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you create your `JScrollPane` with the desired `JTextArea`:

```
static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

And then you recreate it, without the `JTextArea`:

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
```

So, you just need to remove the line mentioned above. I really don't like your GUI class design (those static fields), but it isn't the objective of your question.